# Series of reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry

> [image]
>   The compound given above is subjected to the following reaction (in that order):
>
> 1. $\ce{t-BuOK}$;
> 2. $\ce{CHCl3}$ and $\ce{CH3ONa}$;
> 3. $\ce{H3O+}$ and heat.
>
> Find out the final product.

<sup>[Source](https://brilliant.org/problems/benzenes-derivative/?ref_id=1276373)</sup>

Attempt:

The question involves exocyclic double bond which is less stable than endocyclic double bond, and so I get that the compound should rearrange to five-membered ring containing a double bond.

In the first reaction tertiary butoxide is a bully base, so it should bring about elimination. Hence $\ce{MeOH}$ will be removed and a double bond will be formed:

[image]

However, I could not get how the reaction proceeds. Any ideas?

Comment: Disregard previous comment. Carbene formation requires loss of bromide group...

Comment: Are you sure you drew that bromide in the right place in the product?

Comment: @Zhe I thought that since endocyclic double bond is more stable than exocuclic double bond the ring should expand

Comment: You still haven't answer my question. Are you sure that the bromide is in the 3-position and not the 2-position?

Comment: @Zhe I  am not sure and I am not able to think of any mechanism of  conversion of exocyclic double bond to endocyclic double bond.

Comment: I had some ideas, but I don't have any way of putting the bromide there. That's a bit too weird.

Comment: @Zhe please share your ideas.My attempt might be wrong

Comment: There were two starting points. One was to the a vinyl carbene by removing HBr. The other was to make a cyclobutene, that opens via a pericyclic reaction.

Comment: User 471651: I ask the same question as Zhe. Are you guessing that the cyclopentadiene is the product or was it given as the product of the reaction? Step 1 is most likely a vinyl carbene reaction with ring expansion. Step 2 appears to be dichloro carbene formation. Step 3 looks like acid-catalyzed elimination of methanol. With a response, I will post a mechanism and/or product.

Comment: @user5519 I am not aware of the answer.it is just my attempt.please share your ideas.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Is there any information as to the structure of the product? Your answer is a known cmpd, but not made this way. The first step in the reaction is a known ring expansion. Without any info on the source or product, this question is highly suspect.